# Why scanf is not taking any input and giving Error in hackerearth editor and codeblocks

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to take string input with white spaces.
This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;

    printf("\nEnter the name : ");


    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name); //it does not work

    //getline(cin, name); //it works fine

    cout<<name<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error Massage on hackerearth editor  and codeblocks:

In function ‘int main()’:
16:29: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka class std::basic_string}’ through ‘...’

16:29: warning: format ‘%[^
:string {aka std::basic_string}’ [-Wformat=]
16:30: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int scanf(const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

Comment: You can't use `std::string` with `scanf`, it only works with C data types.

Comment: Use `cin.getline()` to read a line.

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work. Where did you read that this is how you should do it?

Answer (score 0):

`string`, or in fact `std::string`, is a C++ type from the 1990s (ish).

`scanf` is a C function from 1066. It has no idea what to do with a C++ type.

Don't mix and match; either use C++ features or use C features.